# Enlace a la misma página **HTML**

Tags: html, html5, enlaces-ancla

el caso es que he estado intentado crear un enlace a mi página web y por más que lo hago como me dicen, no me funciona.

A ver si me pueden ayudar, lo tengo colocado de la siguiente forma.
Tengo ésta línea al principio de la página y forma parte de una etiqueta **p**.

```
<string><a href="#grillz" title="Más sobre los GRILLZ">GRILLZ</a></string>
```

Y ésta otra más abajo, donde quiero que se dirija.

```
<a name="grillz"><h2>GRILLZ<h2></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la etiqueta a solo redirecciona los elementos de la página que són **id** y tu has puesto el elemento name.

La redirección que has hecho esta bien:

```
<string><a href="#grillz" title="Más sobre los GRILLZ">GRILLZ</a></string>
```

Pero en vez de name utiliza id y no hace falta englobarlo con un enlace simplemento incorporalo en la etiqueta y ya:

```
<h2 id="grillz">GRILLZ<h2>
```

con la etiqueta e enlace sería así:

```
<a id="grillz"><h2>GRILLZ<h2></a>
```

> Esto se debe a que el **atributo name** puede englobar a varias etiquetas, mientras que el **atributo id** solo puede haber uno en toda la página.

Answer (score 0):

Pues simplemente ejecuta algo así:

```html
<p><a href="https://www.google.com">Redireccionar</a></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Si es un enlace hacia una pagina externa o una seccion que no esta en el mismo index.html la url debe ser
< a href="https://www.google.com"> link a mi sitio < /a>

Comment: No, es un enlace a la misma página.

Comment: Pues en la seccion donde te dirijes te falto el  id="grillz"